# Loading a file to a Queue structure

Tags: java, file, methods, queue

i am trying to load a text file that is holding names of students on a waitlist so that i can add them to the queue. when i try to do it this way i am getting errors. does anyone know how i can keep my waitList saved even when i close my program and reopen it?

```
public void loadWaitList() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File wait = new File("waitList.txt");
        Scanner waiting = new Scanner(wait);
        String first,last,id;
        saveClose();

        for(int i =0; i < waiting.nextLine().length(); i++) {
            first = waiting.next();
            last = waiting.next();
            id = waiting.next();
            Student add =new Student(first,last,id);
            waitList.add(add);
        }
        System.out.println(waiting.nextLine());
        waiting.close();
    }
```

Comment: _way i am getting errors_ What errors?

Comment: Can you paste the text of the stack trace into the question, if you are getting an exception. If you are getting the wrong output, then paste the input file, the output file, and the expected output. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are using nextLine() as though it is an array of all lines in the file.  It might be better to change your for loop to a while and use the hasNextLine() method.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html